Has a tire ever exploded inside the Wheel Well?
Amidst the recent Delta tire explosion case with multiple staff fatalities at ATL airport, I wonder if there has been a case where a tire has exploded inside the wheel well?

Yes, of course.
One famous case which eventually led to the use of non-flammable hydraulic fluid was a Swissair Sud Aviation Caravelle which tried to clear up low-lying fog to improve visibility in order to be allowed to take off (Swissair flight 306).
For this, the pilot ran the engines at elevated power and applied brakes, taxiing up and down the foggy runway, which was Swissair standard procedure at that time (1963). The trick worked, exhaust heat made the fog disappear and the airplane could start its journey.
What the pilots did not know: The brake disks were glowing red hot at this time. With the gear down, cooling was already marginal, and once the gear was retracted, the heat quickly dissipated into the magnesium wheel hubs and the tire pressure made them explode. One of the hubs did even disintegrate during take-off, leaving magnesium debris on the runway.
With the still glowing disk brakes and shrapnel from the wheel hubs having cut the hydraulic lines, the hydraulic fluid ignited and started a fire which caused the plane to dive into the ground 35 km from the airport.

interesting technique to disperse fog, didn't knew about it.

The investigation report (German) says that a fire already started on the runway, after the first wheel flange burst (not the tire, btw - not sure whether OP cares). It did not reach a conclusion whether the second wheel burst due to overheating by itself, or due to the fire caused by the broken wheel after gear retraction.

https://admiralcloudberg.medium.com/fire-in-the-fog-the-crash-of-swissair-flight-306-c54893961151

I have an idea: What about if instead they had taxied down the runway few hundred feet, put parking brake & full throttle & back to idle, then move forward again ,few hundred feet more and repeat the process until the required runway distance needed. I don't know how many feet they needed but something like 8 stops? or am I under estimating?

@Gabe: With your proposed technique, by the time they'd reached the end of the runway and returned to the takeoff point the fog there'd've had more than enough time to descend again.

@Vikki yeah I thought about that later I think you're right. I think is time for a new type of invention. There are snow blower, now we need a fog blower. It would be a big turbine
attached to a truck/tug and it will taxi down the runway lol.

@Gabe Actually, the recommended technique was like that: Stop, let the engines blow a tunnel into the fog, move forward, repeat. However, you need to wait to let the engines spool down before releasing the brakes and to spool up after coming to a halt again. The Swissair pilots took shortcuts.
